# Missing texture after add new actors

Tags: libgdx, textures, kotlin

I want to add two types of characters multiple times but when I add a new actor to stage texture in "old" actors stops render.

I can add multiple `KnightActor` (without `RatActor`) or multiple `RatActor` (without `KnightActor`). When I try to add multiple `KnightActor` and `RatActor` on one stage only textures from newest actors are rendered (one `RatActor` and one `KnightActor`)

[image]

GameScreen.kt

```
override fun render(delta: Float) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    actorManager.addNewActors(stage)

    viewPort.camera.update()

    stage.act(delta)
    stage.draw()

    world.step(delta, 8, 3)
    debugger.render(world, viewPort.camera.combined)
}
```

ActorManager.kt

```
fun markToAdd(actor: BaseActor<*>) {
    toAdd.add(actor)
}

fun addNewActors(stage: Stage) {
    toAdd.forEach { actor: BaseActor<*> ->
        stage.addActor(actor)
        actor.addToWorld(worldService.getWorld())
        Gdx.app.log("afterAdd", (++charactersOnStage).toString())
    }
    toAdd.clear()
}
```

KnightActor.kt

```
override fun draw(batch: Batch, parentAlpha: Float) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha)

    if (isMoving) {
        frameStateTime += Gdx.graphics.deltaTime
    }

    // DRAW TEXTURE
    val frame = animationManager.getFrameAndChangeSpeed(AnimationType.KNIGHT_WALK_RIGHT, frameStateTime, getSpeed())
    val frameX: Float = position.x - (size.width / 2)
    val frameY: Float = position.y - (size.height / 2)

    batch.draw(frame, frameX, frameY, size.width, size.height)

    // END DRAW
}
```

RatActor.kt

```
override fun draw(batch: Batch, parentAlpha: Float) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha)

    if (isMoving) {
        frameStateTime += Gdx.graphics.deltaTime
    }

    // DRAW TEXTURE
    val frame = animationManager.getFrameAndChangeSpeed(AnimationType.RAT_WALK_LEFT, frameStateTime, getSpeed())
    val frameX: Float = position.x - (size.width / 2)
    val frameY: Float = position.y - (size.height / 2)

    batch.draw(frame, frameX, frameY, size.width, size.height)

    // END DRAW
}
```

AnimationManager.kt

```
fun getAnimation(animationType: AnimationType): Animation<TextureRegion> {
    return AssetsManager.loadSprite(animationType.spriteFile, animationType.alias).getAnimationForSprite(animationType.alias, animationType.width, animationType.height)
}
fun getFrameAndChangeSpeed(animationType: AnimationType, stateTime: Float, speed: Float, looping: Boolean = true): TextureRegion {
    val animation = getAnimation(animationType)
    animation.frameDuration = 1 / speed
    return animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, looping)
}
```

Comment: Questions about debugging a problem in your game must include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the issue - in this case, you need the code in the question itself. If you've found a solution on an external forum, post it as an Answer in the "Your Answer" box below, [including a link to credit the folks who helped you](https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=29003&p=114011#p114011), as well as a description of the fix so the solution is clear even if the link ever breaks. Don't tack a solution link into the bottom of the question itself - that's not how this Q&A site works.

Answer (score 1):

In `BaseActor` class I was clearing screen with `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`. After removing it, everything works as it should.